# Find the joint cdf of $F(x,y)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, probability-distributions

Given the joint pdf of $(X,Y)$ is $f(x,y)=4x$ for $0<y<x^2$ and $0<x<1$ and 0 otherwise. Find the joint cdf of $F(x,y)$?

---

I am confused about the upper and lower bound in integral. The definition is that
$$
F(x,y)=\int_{-\infty}^y\int_{-\infty}^x (4u) dudv.
$$

Is this one
$$
F(x,y)=\int_{-\infty}^y\int_{-\infty}^x (4u) dudv=\int_{0}^y\int_{0}^x (4u) dudv?
$$

Comment: Lower limits OK but what you have now is an integration over a square, however the domain of $f$ is not the full square.

Comment: @coffeemath How to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $a,b\in [0,1],$

$$F(a,b)=P(X\leq a, Y\leq b)=\int_0^a \int_0^{\min\{x^2,b\}}4x dy dx=\int_0^a 4x \min\{x^2,b\} dx.$$

If $\sqrt{b}\leq a,$

$$F(a,b)=\int_0^\sqrt{b} 4x^3 dx+\int_{\sqrt b}^a 4x b dx=2ba^2-b^2.$$

If $\sqrt b>a,$

$$F(a,b)=\int_0^a4x^3dx=a^4.$$